# Routing Arduino Mega output to either one of two serial ports

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I have an Arduino Mega controller that normally communicates via Bluetooth (HC08 Bluetooth module) to an Android device. In case there is a problem on the Android side I wish to have a fallback ability to communicate via the USB serial port. The choice of serial port is determined by a hardware switch that the Arduino can read. Currently I have:

```
HardwareSerial & Terminal = Serial;
HardwareSerial & BTPort = Serial1;
```

Is there a way to route an output to either BTPort or to terminal, dependent on the state of the switch? Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
HardwareSerial & OutputPort
if(switch_is_on) 
  OutputPort = Terminal;
else
  OutputPort = BTPort;
```

Obviously the above code does not work. I have no idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Like you, I would use a global variable e.g. `switch_is_on` and I would write a method `printSerial( ... )` containing a if else statement that uses the Serial object for the `swich_is_on == true` case and Serial1 for the else case. I would use this method instead of the Serial/Serial1 print methods. Also, to me it is not obvious whay your try should not work. What's the problem (besides the missing semicolon of cause ;-))?

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for your comment. Yes, it solves the problem, but not in the most efficient way. It would be most efficient if one could just re-assign a (pointer to?) a serial port and directly use the println for the re-assigned port. Your suggestion is a very useful work-around, though.

Comment: As I said, I don't know any reason, why you can't assign `Serial` or `Serial1` to a variable of type `HardwareSerial &<name>` like `HardwareSerial &activeSerial = Serial1;` If you declare `activeSerial` as a global variable, you can access it from everywhere. I just don't know why it is obvious that this shouldn't work. At least for me it should. If you only want to use pointer, use `HardwareSerial *activeSerial = &Serial` and `activeSerial->print...`.

Comment: But, I would prefer the printMethod because it is the most effective way. What happens if you change the switching flag while the program is running? If you have a predefined activeSerial variable nothing happens. The method would use the other Serial intead. You see the idea?

Comment: FYI: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=358740.0

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, reference must be assigned at definition

Comment: I have:  ```HardwareSerial *Myserial;  Myserial = Serial1;```  This gives an error: Myserial does not name a type.

Comment: Only initialization is allowed at global scope, e.g. `HardwareSerial *hs = &Serial1;`. Or do the assignment in a function.

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for pointing that out, I did not explain it clearly. References (<Type> &) must be declared and  initialized together, so they can not be used to compute alternative references later on. But pointer have no such restrictions. Willem, I'm sorry that I did not mentioned that. I simply did not think so far. ;-)

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you everyone that responded.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three distinct ways (and one that is similar to another) of doing what you want.

But first a note on *polymorphism*.  The `HardwareSerial` class is itself a child of the `Stream` class. It's this `Stream` class that provides all the read/write functionality (it, itself, is a child of the `Print` class which provides all the `print(...)` functions).

If all you want to do is print then you should be working with the `Print` class. if you want to do both reading and writing then the `Stream` class is what you want. You should only use `HardwareSerial` if you *need* to use the Serial-specific functions like `.begin(baud)`.

So with that in mind you could:

## 1. Assign a pointer

```cpp
Print *printer;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
    printer = &Serial;
}

void loop() {
    printer = &Serial;
    printer->println(millis());
    delay(100);
    printer = &Serial1;
    printer->println(millis());
    delay(100);
}
```

This is by far the most efficient method from a purely machine perspective.

Note the use of `->` instead of `.` when calling a function on a pointer.

## 2a. Use a wrapper function

```cpp
uint8_t stream = 0;

void printit(const char *text) {
    switch (stream) {
        case 0: 
            Serial.print(text);
            break;
        case 1:
            Serial1.print(text);
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    stream = 0;
    printit("Hello on stream 0\r\n");
    stream = 1;
    printit("Hello on stream 1\r\n");
}
```

This is less efficient and limits what you can print unless you write lots of overloaded functions.

## 2b. Use a macro

This is like 2a but uses a macro instead of a function:

```cpp
#define printit(T) if (stream == 0) Serial.print(T) else Serial1.print(T)
```

This keeps the standard overloading of the print function but has lots of IF statements littered through your code. A fraction more efficient than 2a since it's all inline. Harder for a human to understand though.

## 3. Create a wrapper class

This is the rolls-royce method. Everything becomes encapsulated in your own object. Pointers are used to keep it efficient.

```cpp
class Printer : public Print {
    private:
        Print *stream;
        Print *stream0;
        Print *stream1;
    public:
        Printer(Print &s0, Print &s1) : stream0(&s0), stream1(&s1) {
            stream = &s0;
        }
        size_t write(uint8_t c) {
            return stream->write(c);
        }
        void setStream(uint8_t sno) {
            switch (sno) {
                case 0: stream = stream0; break;
                case 1: stream = stream1; break;
            }
        }
};

Printer printer(Serial, Serial1);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    printer.setStream(0);
    printer.println(millis());
    delay(100);
    printer.setStream(1);
    printer.prinln(millis());
    delay(100);
}
```

With this method the new class could be put into a library and used across your projects.

You also get all the functions you'd normally get with the `Serial` object when printing (for reading change `Print` to `Stream` and implement all the *pure virtual* functions you need for that class).

And a footnote for all those that say "Why use pointers? Why not references?" I say: I hate references. Pointers are far more obvious what they are. References you can't tell apart from distinct variables. With a pointer you know it's a pointer. References are the spawn of the devil.

Comment: This is a complete explanation that clears up the problem. Thank you for your time.